# Integrate an existing cookie authentication provider with identityserver3

Tags: authentication, cookies, identityserver3

Here's my problem:

I have an existing authentication provider (I control the source code) that uses OWIN cookies for authentication. The login process has many steps with custom screens. Now I want to integrate that provider with identityserver3.

Here are my ideas:

A: Implement a dummy view service for identityserver3 that does meta redirect to the login page of my existing provider. The bad part is when I have to finish the login process, because the only way i see is to self-post a form to identityserver3 with the user name and password.

B: I can have identityserver3 in my provider project and render the entry login screen of my provider (there's a very hacky example in the sources for MVC) , but again, like point A, in the end i have to somehow post user name and password back to identityserver3

C: use the external providers in identityserver3. For that I need to automatically redirect to my provider and register a custom authentication middle-ware. Because our provider is a standard OWIN coookie provider I thought I could use Katana's CookieAuthenticationMiddleware but that does not seem to work.

What is the right way to achieve what I want (integrate my cookie provider with identityserver3)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option D: Use the OWIN environment extension methods to tell IdSvr who your user is: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/owin.html. This will still have IdSvr issue its own cookie, though. It might just make sense to drop your own cookie middleware, and let IdSvr manage the cookie.

Comment: Thanks - it worked! I used the extensions to get the partial redirect URL and update the partial login cookie in combination with extending UserServiceBase and initiating the partial login.